# Searching for the best way to create a field of Text Edits or something like that

Tags: c++, qt

I am terrible new to Qt programming, so I wan't to code some simple first projects.

I am trying to create a soduko solver. The problem is, that I now use 9^2 text edits to creat the "sudoke field". I think this is a terrible way to solve this.
Is there a good way in Qt to solve my problem? Like a matrix-text-edit-class or some shortcuts i could use. Working with 9^2 text edits is a little bit annoying.
Thanks for any suggestions and your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`QTableWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qtablewidget.html) (or a `QTableView`) with 9 columns and 9 rows:

[image]

Comment: This looks perfect! I searched pretty long and couldn't find this one. Thank you very much. I will try it today! If it's working well, I am going to mark your answer as right.

Comment: Although it might work as a quick n' dirty solution, I'm sure that in a couple of hours you'll be smashing your head trying to make those lines thicker, or center the text in the cells, or allow for just one digit input, and so on. ***You've found a hammer, and now everything looks like a nail.*** Do not do that. Just create a *custom widget* that displays a sudoku board. It's an interesting exercise. There are a couple of examples shipped with Qt to get you started.

Comment: I laughed a lot, cause there is some truth in the smashing your head part ;). I tried it, but there were some problems with the qtablewidget. It might be a solution to my question above, but it's a little bit (very) hard to make some own changes (at least for me). But i learned a lot. Tomorrow i am going to learn more about custom widgets. Thanks for the tip!